# Bash: base64 decode a file x times

Tags: bash, base64

During a scripting challenge, it was asked to me to decode X times (saying 100) a base64 files (base64.txt).
So I wrote this small bash script to do so.

```sh
for item in `cat base64.txt`;do
   for count in {1..100};do
      if [ $count -eq 1 ]; then
         current=$(echo "$item" |base64 --decode)
      else
         current=$(echo "$current" |base64 --decode)
      fi
      if [ $count -eq 100 ]; then
         echo $current
      fi
   done
done
```

It is working as expected, and I got the attended result.
What I am looking for now, is a way to improve this script, because I am far to be a specialist, and want to see what could improve the way I approach this kind of challenge.

Could some of you please give me some advice ?

Comment: `if [ $count -eq 50 ]; then` - what for are you iterating up until 100, if you output only at 50? You are decoding 50 times the _words_ from single file base64.txt, is this intended? You describe it as "base64 files" which means there are multiple files, yet you parse only one.

Comment: I just edit my script. I was a manual modification, to avoid people looking for response directly here. Sorry for that.

Comment: In fact, there is only 1 file, that contains 1 line in it. And the text of this line have been encode 100 times using base64. Hoping to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> decode X times (saying 100) a base64 file (base64.txt)
>
> there is only 1 file, that contains 1 line in it.

Just read the content of the file, decode it 100 times and output.

```
state=$(<base64.txt)
for i in {1..100}; do
   state=$(<<<"$state" base64 --decode)
done
echo "$state"
```

Notes:

- Backticks `` ` `` are discouraged. Use `$(...)` instead. [bash deprecated and obsolete syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)
- `for i in cat` is a common antipattern in bash. [How to read a file line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- If the file contains one line only, there is no need to iterate over the words in the file.
- In bash `echo "$item" |` is a useless usage of `echo` (and is also a small risk that it may not work, when ex. `item=-e`). You can use a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) instead when in bash.

Comment: That is exactly working as expected. And this is a far way more efficient and clean method. In addition, it is executing 40% rapidly than mine. And thank you for the detailed explanation. I will work on these recommendations.

Comment: @Julien if speed is a concern, then you shouldn't decode the file over and over.

Comment: @oguz, speed isn't a concern, it was simply to highlight the crappiness of my method. I will work on applying best practices on bash scripting.